# Rails - how can I introduce asset compilation for an app getting upgraded 3.0.10 -> 3.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm upgrading a rails application.

I've updated the Gemfile with the change from version `3.0.10` to `3.1.6`

The upgrade didn't 'switch' the app to using assets (there is no app/assets folder).

Should I just add the folder manually?

I'm looking to deploy the upgrade to Heroku (which is running the 3.0.10 app ok).
What else should I change?

Looks like `config/application.rb` needs this line inside the application class definition: `config.assets.enabled = true` ?  Right now that line doesn't exist at all in that file..

Thanks!

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1

Answer (score 0):

There's a rake task for updating rails apps with new config files and so on. `rake rails:update`. See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html - specifically the stuff you need to add to `config/application.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I work with Ruby on Rails, assets pipeline is one of the biggest change I know. Unfortunately, there is no automatic way to upgrade an app to assets pipeline.

Basically the whole process upgrade process is (it may take 1 or 2 full days!):

- learn about assets pipeline from [Rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)
- upgrade your config files (`rake rails:update`) to enable assets pipeline
- move all of your assets (js/css/images) to `app/assets/` or `vendor/assets/` folders
- create manifest files in these folders (read [this doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives))
- change references to assets everywhere in the app using [asset helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)
- check that your app is still working :)
- try assets compilation in local by running `rake assets:precompile`
- deploy to Heroku (and make sure your app is using Heroku Cedar stack). Read this [troubleshooting guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar)

Good luck :)